# Divide polygon layer by point layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, fields-attributes

I have two layers - one polygon layer that is a buffer of a road layer, and one point layer that shows certain locations along that road.

What I want to do is to divide/split the polygon layer at the exact locations of the point layer. I also need the divided polygon layer to include attributes from the *point* layer.

Any ideas on how to do this in QGIS?

EDIT: I need the buffer to be 5-15 meters from the road.

Thanks!

Comment: Is splitting the line/road layer an option (before buffering)? Would be easier.

Comment: It might be, but I want the buffer be rectangular, 15 meters from the road on both sides.

Comment: You can make buffers with square ends using GRASS v.buffer.distance from the Sextante toolbox.

Comment: I've tried to split the line/road, but I seem to have another problem - the points aren't always located on the line. It may differ a few meters. Ideas?